# How to remove one of the duplicate values that are next to each other in a list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

```
x1 = [5, 5]
x2 = [1, 5, 5, 2]
x3 = [5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 5]
x4 = [5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5]
x5 = [5, -5]
x6 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x7 = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

How do I remove one of the *duplicate values that are next to each other* on every list?

After all one of the duplicate values that are next to each other are removed, they should look like this:

```
x1 = [5]
x2 = [1, 5, 2]
x3 = [5, 1, 2, 5]
x4 = [5, 1, 5, 2, 5]
x5 = [5, -5]
x6 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x7 = [5]
```

Comment: What happens if there are three values in a row?

Comment: Well its still a duplicate, two values of the same will be removed and one will remain. Edit: Added x7

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: You should respect others in SO. Not everyone is a professional, geniuses, and such, like you. Some are just newbie, curious, hobbyist and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there can be three or more values in a row and only a single value is wanted:

```
from itertools import groupby

def remove_consecutive_duplicates(iterable):
    return [v for v, g in groupby(iterable)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple list comprehension would do:

```
>>> x = [5, 5, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5]
>>> [a for a, b in zip(x, x[1:]) if a != b] + [x[-1]]
[5, 1, 5, 2, 5]
```

You are basically taking each element if the next one differs, plus the last element.

Comment: I hate to see someone give out homework answers to questioners who've shown no effort.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I usually do as well, except this is no homework (maybe learning) and it asks for a half-trivial solution, meaning it doesn't have an half-baked solution

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of SO? To ask questions you don't know? How can I attempt to answer something I don't know? I made an effort to search for this problem in SO and Google and found no similar questions. What do you expect me to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over your list while keeping track of the previous value, and only keep the next value if they differ:

```
def uniquefy_conseq_vals(my_list):
    prev = None
    new_list = []
    for ele in my_list:
        if ele != prev:
            new_list.append(ele)
        prev = ele
    return new_list

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x1 = [5, 5]
    x2 = [1, 5, 5, 2]
    x3 = [5, 5, 1, 2, 5, 5]
    x4 = [5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5]
    x5 = [5, -5]
    x6 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    x7 = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]

    print uniquefy_conseq_vals(x1)
    print uniquefy_conseq_vals(x2)
    print uniquefy_conseq_vals(x3)
    print uniquefy_conseq_vals(x4)
    print uniquefy_conseq_vals(x5)
    print uniquefy_conseq_vals(x6)
    print uniquefy_conseq_vals(x7)
```